# How assign a value to a variable inside a for loop in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, for

I'd like to evaluate the variable called arduino outside the for loop, but it always gives me 0.

```
arduino=0
for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
    (
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && continue
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && continue
        dispositivo="/dev/$devname - $ID_SERIAL"
        if [[ $dispositivo == *"Arduino"* ]]; then
            arduino=1
            echo 'CONNECTED DEVICE'
        fi
    )
done

if [ $arduino -eq 1 ]; then
    echo 'CONNECTED DEVICE'
else
    echo 'DISCONNECTED DEVICE'
fi
```

Comment: I suggest to remove `(` after `do`  and `)` before `done`.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: It works!! Thanks, what a very simple solution, can you explain me why? I'm new in bash programming

Comment: See choroba's answer.

Answer (score 8):

Parentheses `( ... )` introduce a subshell. Variables in a subshell are inherited from the parent shell, but aren't propagated back to it.

Removing the parentheses should make it work.